# How to obtain $\mu\left(T,P\right)$ form the potential $U=\alpha\frac{S^4}{N^2V}$

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I have this homework where i need to derive $\mu\left(T,P\right)$ from $U=\alpha\frac{S^4}{N^2V}$ where $\alpha$ is a constant positive, i've been trying some ways, one of them is using the Gibbs' relations for T,P and $\mu$, but i get realtions dependent of S, V and N, i´m trying to substitute all values in order to get a relation between $\mu$, T and P but i don´t know if this is right because i can't reach that relation.

One friend suggest me to use the Gibbs Free energy but since i'm suppose to not know this from my class yet (we haven't derive it) i don´t know if that is the only way to reach the result i'm aiming for,

Comment: Start with $dU=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$

Comment: yes, i have this:
$T= 4\alpha\frac{S^3}{N^2V}$;
$P= \alpha\frac{S^4}{N^2V^2}$;
$\mu= -2\alpha\frac{S^4}{N^3V}$
But i can't express $\mu$ using T and P

Comment: Try again.  The algebra should work out.

Answer (score 1):

If you write s=S/N and v=V/N, you obtain:

$$T=4\alpha\frac{s^3}{v}$$ 
$$P=\alpha\frac{s^4}{v^2}$$and
$$\mu=-2\alpha\frac{s^4}{v}$$
So, solve the first two equations for s and v exclusively in terms of T and P, and substitute the results into the equation for $\mu$